# Android - ID used dynamically

Tags: android

I am useing custom ListView and for each row of data I want to add specific Id to address it and work with it further. Is there any way, how to set Id in XML file something like @+id/idImageView +i, where i is i++? Is there any way?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own Adapter and add it to ListView. The adapter can be based on [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) or it's subclasses.
Override method getItemId() as you like.

Simple example for ArrayAdapter containing objects with id property.

```
public class MySimpleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MySimpleObject> {

    public MySimpleAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<MySimpleObject> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        //here create or recycle your view
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return getItem(position).id;
    }


    public static class MySimpleObject {
        long id;
        String text;
    }
}
```

For simple objects in array [here is example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html).

To use Strings in xml look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray)

Comment: Thanks, I thought that I have set it up first to be afterwards able to get this item id, am I right?

Comment: Edited my answer. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do? Why cant you use the position information and map it to your array of data. The rows displayed in ListView are recycled, meaning if you have 1000 rows of data, you will NOT have unique 1000 rows to display. I guess only 10, or may be less, views are unique and they are recycled every time you scroll up or down. So you cant use the id's of these rows to uniquely fetch/identify your data. Refer to the post below.

http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296